# Нет перевода для кнопки сохранения при попытке добавить избранные/игнорируемые метки в настройках профиля участника

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

На [вкладке избранных/игнорируемых меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/tag-notifications/current) в профиле отсутствует перевод слова Done:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В трансе, я так понимаю, это строка под ключом [f92965e2c8a7afb3c1b9a5c09a263636](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/136757567?q=key%3Af92965e2c8a7afb3c1b9a5c09a263636).

Сложно сказать, где ещё эта строка используется, но я бы предложил либо "Готово", либо "Сохранить".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Утвердил вариант «Готово».

При этом, насколько я помню, перевод там раньше был, так как я исследовал этот функционал.